# In Django, is request.META[] the right place to add specific information for a request?

Tags: python, django, request, tastypie

I'm using Django, and want to store data that is relevant only for the duration of a request, and not on the session.

Is it correct to add something to request.META, like:

```
request.META['acl'] = acl
```

In my situation, I am using Tastypie, with a custom authorization class, and need a way to pass data between functions... it seems like storing something on the request would be the right thing to do... I just don't know where to store such information.  My class looks something like:

```
class MyAuthorization(Authorization):
    def is_authorized(self, request, object=None):
        acl = getMyAccessControlList(request.method,request.session['username'])
        for permission in acl:
            if permission in self.permissions[request.method]:
                request.META['acl'] = acl
                return True
        return False

    def apply_limits(self, request, object_class, rs):
        if 'HAS_ALL_ACCESS' in request.META['acl']:
                return rs
        else if 'HAS_USER_ACCESS' in request.META['acl']:
                rs = rs.filter(object_class.user==request.session['username'])
                return rs
```

Futher, Tastypie creates a single REST resource object, with a single authorization class used by all threads, so it's not thread-safe to just put it on the authorization class.

**UPDATE**

As per Chris Pratt's feedback, **no**, it doesn't make sense to modify the request.  Exploring further, it appears to be appropriate to modify the request initially through custom middleware, and then keep it constant for the rest of the request:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/middleware

In this case, the middleware will look something like:

```
class AccessControlListMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self,request,view_func,view_args,view_kwargs):
        permissions = set()
        for role in request.session['permissions']:
            for permission in PERMISSION_LIST[request.method][role]:
                permissions.add(permission)
        request.acl = list(permissions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Don't mess with the `request` object. Especially since these are methods on the same class, you should simply assign data to `self`:

```
self.acl = getMyAccessControlList(request.method,request.session['username'])

...

if 'HAS_ALL_ACCESS' in self.acl:
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, with tastypie, it create a single Authorization class (along with the REST interface), so it's not thread-safe... but maybe I'm missing something there.

Comment: I see. Well, you could use a thread local, but I'm not sure that's really any better. I suppose there's nothing *technically* wrong with adding something to `request`, but I wouldn't mess with `META` specifically. The all-upper attributes on `request` are meant to indicate that they're constants, so it's not appropriate to modify them even if you *can*.

Comment: Got it - it looks like the appropriate place to add information to the request is through middleware, and I'll create my own request.acl for this information, which works AND feels more grammatically correct.  Thanks again.